# Cannot connect to remote MSSQL on Azure VM(classic)

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to connect to an SQLEXPRESS database on an Azure VM(classic). My local machine is a Mac with [sql-cli](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sql-cli) installed.

I have created a user within SQL Management Studio that is set to SQL Server authentication. I can connect with the credentials using SQL Management Studio on the server.

I have opened TCP 1433 in Windows (Server 2012) Firewall. I have added an endpoint in Azure for port 1433.

TCP/IP is enabled within SQL Server Configuration Manager.

I'm connecting with:

> mssql -s [IP address] -u [user] -p [password] -d [database]

And I get the following message:

> Error: Failed to connect to [Ip address]:1433 in 15000ms

What else can I check?

Comment: `-e` is integrated security, so why are you passing a username and password too?

Comment: If you can't telnet to [IP address] on port 1433 then the mssql can't connect either. Seems like 1) your endpoint configuration isn't working as you expect or 2) SQL Server Express isn't actually listening on 0.0.0.0:1433 since, by default, its TCP/IP protocol is disabled.

Comment: I can't telnet on port 1433. I definitely have an Endpoint setup in Azure for public and private port 1433. TCP/IP is enabled in SQL Server Configuration Manager, however, I see that none of the IP address are set to 'Enabled'. There's only one IP4 address and it doesn't match the IP listed in Azure. I tried enabling all the addresses and restarting SQL Server process, but still can't connect

Comment: Also tried updating the IP4 address to the one I'm expecting - still can't connect